# How do I duplicate ActiveResource::Error object?

Tags: ruby, activeresource

I'm performing an operation on a `base_user`. I want my `@user`'s errors to be the same as the `base_user`'s because I end up showing those errors as a banner in the view. But, I don't know how to set the `@user`'s errors. Here is what I'm doing:

```
  base_user.validate_password_change(params)
  if base_user.errors.size > 0
    #@user.errors.initialize_dup(base_user.errors) # does not work
    @user.errors = base_user.errors.dup # does not work
    raise 'Validation Errors' if @user.errors.size > 0
  end
```

`@user.errors` is an empty hash. base_user.errors.messages is a hash containing an array named password with elements (strings of reasons why password is not properly formatted). According to the [ActiveResource API](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activeresource/4.0.0/frames), ActiveResource::Error objects can do `from_array`, `from_hash` (not listed in API but I see it in code), `from_json`, and `from_xml`, but it doesn't have an initialize or setter.

I'm using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0.0, which uses ActiveResource 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveResource::Errors inherits from [ActiveModel::Errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html).

You can overwrite the errors on the `@user` instance by enumerating the attributes of `base_user`:

```
base_user.errors.each do |name, value|
  @user.errors.set(name, value)
end
```

You may need to consider the case where you have errors on both objects, and overwriting one with the other might not be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't doing what I wanted, but knowing about the .set helped me solve my problem.